# ASP.NET Select control

Tags: .net

I have a HTML Select dropdown control from which I can select a customer, I have a Gridview which gets populated with data from the customer select dropdown control and a button which brings data back to the Gridview but the select dropdown control gets reset every time when there is a post back, how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Knockout (to update when data changes) and AJAX (to send the data without refreshing the screen).

Comment: You can always implement a partial postback using an AJAX update panel. Only those elements that you desire will render the postback effect. The rest will maintain their state.
Read:-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx
Stackoverflow has a couple of questions regarding how to work with partial postbacks. search for these topics, they maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use a full post for the page:

After you do your 'postback' you have to set the selected item again in controller.

something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getDetails(int customerId){
       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list=
                customers.Select(o => new SelectListItem() {Value = o.Id.ToString(), Text = o.Name, selected = (o.id == customerId)})
       // the rest of your action
}
```

This has to be done every time you do a full page request via the controller.